# gh action if condition always passes

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Working on a Github workflow that has many gh actions and needs to control based on a condition. To achieve this, I added an if condition with a variable (`v`), which contains 'true' or 'false' .

```
- name: gh action with if
  uses: ./.github/actions/custom-action
  if: ${{ matrix.v == 'true' }}
  with:
    function-name: ${{ steps.setup_files.outputs.functionName }}
```

The matrix I am using

```
"{\"function\": \"func1\", \"v\": \"true\" },"
"{\"function\": \"func2\", \"v\": \"false\" },"
```

But the gh action always executes irrespective of the value of `v`. When I ran the workflow with debug mode, I found the expression that evaluates caused the issue.

```
(success() && format('{0} == ''false''', matrix.v))
```

Ideally, it should be

```
(success() && (matrix.v == 'false'))
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the matrix you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am reading that correctly, but it looks like the variable is called `cond` so you would call it using `matrix.cond` not `matrix.v`. If that isn't correct, can you post the matrix exactly how it looks in the YAML file?

Comment: @AliSamji yes, that's my bad. But the problem related to this
https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1173

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducing example (full YAML that somebody could copy and paste to see the behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

following [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif), condition should not be between `${{ ... }}`:

```yaml
- name: gh action with if
  uses: ./.github/actions/custom-action
  if: matrix.v == 'true'
  with:
    function-name: ${{ steps.setup_files.outputs.functionName }}
```

Comment: I tried this too and still getting the same issue

Comment: and checking as a boolean?